# Does `mv` just unlink and relink? Or does it actually somehow change the file metainfo in place?

Tags: mv

I was looking through a Git tutorial, where it said basically that all `git mv` does is remove from index, and add to index with a different name, so I wondered about how the actual `mv` UNIX Utility worked.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mv

Comment: In general these types of basic questions are well covered already on wikipedia, I'd start there, and then if you have more deeply rooted questions, bring them here.

Comment: @slm oh wow, didn't know Wikipedia has entire articles for single UNIX utilities. Thanks for pointing this out to me; I'll definitely do that in the future.

Comment: Yeah they're a very useful resource b/c they typically boil down to the key bits of each cli.